# How to write cron expression for specific weeks?

Tags: java, javascript, cronexpression

How do I write a cron expression for specific weeks? say If I want a job to execute on mon, Tue and Sunday of 1st and 3rd week OR say the last week of the month of the say 1st and 9th Month?

Days will range from mon to sunfday i.e. all days in a week. One day or any combination of the days. e.g. Mon,tue or only mon

Months can range from jan to dec. One or multiple months.

Weeks will range from 1 to 4 or last week. Single or multiple weeks.

Thanks.

Comment: In Java, in JavaScript or in Cron? Those are three very different things.

Comment: In java or javascript. Mostly javascript

Comment: check this [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/601660/223699). might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with a typical crontab, because there's no "week in month" setting.

Your best bet would be to run a shell script on each day from cron, and then check within the script if the day matches the day, and first or last week of the month using the %c function in dconv from dateutils (http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#dconv).

The %c format option means: The count of the weekday within the month (range 00 to 05)